# Error 422 when trying to validate Laravel Form via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, validation

I have been trying to use Larave's Validator class.  I can get it to work when submitting a form normally, but when I submit via AJAX I get an error:

```
POST http://localhost/dashboard 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Even when I try the simple version of my form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            @if ($errors->any())
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <div>
                        {{ $error }}
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
            <form action="/dashboard" method="post" id="test-form"> 
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#test-form').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize())
        .fail(function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .done(function(res)
        {
            alert('done');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate(['name' => 'required']);

        echo 'submitted';
    }
}
```

The goal is to submit a form, but for right now I just want the errors to be returned through an AJAX request.  I am using Laravel 5.6.

When I get the error, the Console.log does print out, and the Status Test is what is showing as Unprocessable Entity.

Edit:  Here is the data from my console log:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ ( statusText )
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ ( fn )
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ ( type )
pipe
:
ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ ( obj )
readyState
:
4
responseJSON
:
errors
:
{name: Array(1)}
message
:
"The given data was invalid."
__proto__
:
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ toString()
valueOf
:
ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__
:
ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__
:
ƒ __proto__()
responseText
:
"{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"name":["The name field is required."]}}"
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ ( name, value )
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
422
statusCode
:
ƒ ( map )
statusText
:
"Unprocessable Entity"
then
:
ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: Can you post the `data` from your console log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 422 response is returned by Laravel when an Ajax request is made and has validation errors. Inspect the response in your browser's console - it should show you JSON that includes the validation errors with your request. It's likely that your jQuery code to post to Laravel isn't sending the form attributes the way you expect.

Comment: Ok, so this is normal then and as long as my JSON errors are there I should not worry about the error and just parse the response?

Comment: Thank you.  I am able to get my data out properly by ignoring the error.